# How to wrap graphs by categories while keeping the same width of bars with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am struggling with using `facet_grid()` and `facet wrap()` with `ggplot()`. I would like to be able to wrap the different stacked barcharts for every two categories (of the variable `Department` here) but at the same time have the same width of bars. The first action can be achieved with `facet wrap()` while the second one can be achieved with `facet_grid()`. I would like to combine the advantages of both functions. Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem please?

The data is:

```
ID<-c("001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008","009","010","NA","012","013")
Name<-c("Damon Bell","Royce Sellers",NA,"Cali Wall","Alan Marshall","Amari Santos","Evelyn Frye","Kierra Osborne","Mohammed Jenkins","Kara Beltran","Davon Harmon","Kaitlin Hammond","Jovany Newman")
Sex<-c("Male","Male","Male",NA,"Male","Male",NA,"Female","Male","Female","Male","Female","Male")
Age<-c(33,27,29,26,27,35,29,32,NA,25,34,29,26)
UKCountry<-c("Scotland","Wales","Scotland","Wales","Northern Ireland","Wales","Northern Ireland","Scotland","England","Northern Ireland","England","England","Wales")
Department<-c("Sports and travel","Sports and travel","Sports and travel","Health and Beauty Care","Sports and travel","Home and lifestyle","Sports and travel","Fashion accessories","Electronic accessories","Electronic accessories","Health and Beauty Care","Electronic accessories",NA)
```

The code is:

```
data<-data.frame(ID,Name,Sex,Age,UKCountry,Department)

## Frequency Table
dDepartmentSexUKCountry <- data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Department) & !is.na(Sex) & !is.na(UKCountry)) %>%
  group_by(Department,Sex,UKCountry) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  mutate(Total = sum(Count), Percentage = round(Count/Total,3)) 

## Graph
dSexDepartmentUKCountry %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sex,
             y=Percentage,
             fill=UKCountry)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position="fill") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Percentage*100,0),"%\n(", Count, ")")), 
            position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), color="white") + 
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
       axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1)) + 
  #facet_grid(cols = vars(Department),scales = "free", space = "free")
  facet_wrap(. ~ Department, scales = "free", ncol = 2)
```

When using `facet_wrap()`, I get:
[image]

When using `facet_grid()`, I get:
[image]

Ideally, I would like to have (edited on Paint):

[image]

I have researched my issue and often I would find one or the other solution but not a combination of both.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the `facet_grid` version and the mockup at the end? You don't want all the facets on one row?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to control how many facets I want in different rows because I have other categorical variables with more than 7 categories as facets and it becomes a lot in one row. On the other hand I want to keep the same width for all columns!

Comment: `facet_grid` won't do that, because it only puts a single variable along one dimension. You could split the data into chunks of however many facets you want on a row, map over them to make identical plots, then stick them together with something like `patchwork` or `cowplot`. Not sure if it's visible to you, but I can see that @stefan posted and deleted an answer that looks like a good use of `ggh4x` for this—maybe they'll undelete it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you send a sample of code of what you think could work? @stefan, could you share again your code using ggh4x please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following acceptable?

[image]

I get this by removing `scales = "free"` from `facet_wrap()`. The columns are the same width. You may prefer to not have the open space where one gender does have any data for the department. However, I think this is easier to read as the category axis labels are in the same place on each plot (Female on left and Male on right) and this plot clearly conveys that there are some departments where Female or Male customers make no purchases.

Here is the code:

```
dDepartmentSexUKCountry %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sex,
             y=Percentage,
             fill=UKCountry)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position="fill") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Percentage*100,0),"%\n(", Count, ")")), 
            position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), color="white") + 
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1)) + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ Department,  ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Dear @Ben Norris, thank you very much for answering my question very quickly! This is fantastic but ideally, I would like to not have the open space where one gender does not have any data for the department as you mentionned. If there is no other solution, I will take your idea :) Thanks again and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with splitting the data into a set number of rows and assembling a grid of plots with `patchwork`. This is necessary because `facet_grid` won't break data in multiple ways along the same dimension, i.e. it won't break data into groups along the x-axis but also wrap them around into multiple rows, and `facet_wrap` doesn't have the flexibility of free spacing. This is definitely more complex than its worth for something small, but it's a process I've used for graphics that need to get a bunch of information together for publishing. Depends on your situation.

The basic idea here is to divvy up what will become bars into 2 rows of panels. It's a bit tricky because each bar is a combination of department and sex (hence using `interaction`), and you're not splitting by the number of observations, you're splitting by unique identifiers. You could do this different ways, but the way that made sense to me was with `rleid` to get group numbers, then scale that based on how many rows you need. After that, split and make the same type of plot for what will become each row. You need country to be a factor and for the fill scale to not drop missing factor levels so you can make sure all the plots have the same legend.

```r
rows <- 2

# only difference between data here & OP is I ungrouped it
dept_ids <- dDepartmentSexUKCountry %>%
  mutate(UKCountry = as.factor(UKCountry),
         id = data.table::rleid(interaction(Department, Sex)),
         row = ceiling(id / max(id) * rows))
dept_ids
#> # A tibble: 9 × 8
#>   Department             Sex    UKCountry     Count Total Percentage    id   row
#>   <chr>                  <chr>  <fct>         <int> <int>      <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Electronic accessories Female England           1     2       0.5      1     1
#> 2 Electronic accessories Female Northern Ire…     1     2       0.5      1     1
#> 3 Electronic accessories Male   England           1     1       1        2     1
#> 4 Fashion accessories    Female Scotland          1     1       1        3     1
#> 5 Health and Beauty Care Male   England           1     1       1        4     2

plots <- dept_ids %>%
  split(.$row) %>%
  purrr::map(function(df) {
    ggplot(df, aes(x=Sex,
               y=Percentage,
               fill=UKCountry)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity",
               position="fill") + 
      geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Percentage*100,0),"%\n(", Count, ")")), 
                position=position_fill(vjust=0.5), color="white") + 
      theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
      facet_grid(cols = vars(Department),scales = "free", space = "free") +
      scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
  })

patchwork::wrap_plots(plots, nrow = rows, guides = "collect")
```

[image]

One issue with this is that you have duplicate x-axis titles. Since the title in this case is pretty self-explanatory, you could just drop it altogether, or you can turn it off in all the plots' themes, patch them together, and then turn it back on for the last plot. Whatever is last in line going into `patchwork`'s assembly functions is what receives the theme setting.

```r
plots %>%
  purrr::map(~. + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())) %>%
  patchwork::wrap_plots(nrow = rows, guides = "collect") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text())
```

[image]

Like I said, in many cases this will be more work than it's worth, but I tried to keep it flexible enough for larger-scale projects where it does make sense.